# How to write a single query for the below scenario?

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am new to SQL and I am facing a problem in writing a query for one scenario. I have 3 tables:

- Table 1 has actor names and movie-id's

  ```
  Table1      
  Actor-ID  Actor-name    Movies_id
  ```
- Table 2 has movie-id's and corresponding movie names.

  ```
  Table2          
  Movies_id   Movies_name
  ```
- Table 3 has movie-id's and corresponding revenue generated by the movies.

  ```
  Table3  
  Movies_id   Revenue_generated
  ```

I want to write a query to fetch data for the below scenario:
All the movies of any one actor which has earned more than [100 crores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system).

I haven't mention any data in the tables, so feel free to add data from your side.

Comment: Thank you Jens for editing. Can you answer the above question?

Comment: Go through some tutorials for how to join two tables and use where condition. Try this 
select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.Movies_id = t2.Movies_id
join table3 t3 on t2.Movies_id = t3.Movies_id
where Revenue_generated > 1000000000 .

Comment: On a side note: This is a bad database design. You should have an actor table with the actor_id and the name. The movie table (your table2), an actor_movie table with both IDs to say which actor played in which movie (n:m relation). And then have your revenues, either as a total in the movie table or as single revenues in a separate table that still must be added up. Apropos: Does your table3 allow multiple entries for one movies_id?

Comment: @thorsten yes you are right. Table2 should have Id's column for both movie and actor. And Table 3 doesn't allow multiple entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-design the database with these tables:

- actor (actor_id, name)
- movie (movie_id, name, revenue)
- actor_movie (actor_id, movie_id)

And the query would be:

```
select *
from movie
where revenue > 1000000000
and movie_id in
(
  select movie_id
  from actor_movie      
  where actor_id = (select actor_id from actor where name = 'Bruce Willis')
);
```

Comment: I guess (there is no need for 3rd table actor_movie and ) we have to create one more column actor_id in Movie table, after that the above query will work. Please let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the edit thorsten. Now, above query will do the work.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was to quick to send this, so my first query was incorrect which I repaired immediately the minute after. The actor_movie table is there to establish the n:m relation between actor and movie (one actor can play in several movies, several actors can play in one movie).

Comment: @Mustang92 you should have told that you're open to design edits. I gave my answer below based on your design.

Comment: @Prabhat G: I generally agree. We should not blindly write queries without even mentioning the flaws in the design, though. (In the given design we might not find all movies an actor played in due to data inconsistencies, i.e. different names for the same actor_id.)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out.

```
SELECT
    A.Actor-name,B.Movies_name
        FROM
            table1 A INNER JOIN table2 ON
                A.Movies_id= B.Movies_id
            INNER JOIN table3 C ON
                A.Movies_id= C.Movies_id
        WHERE C.Revenue_generated > 10000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Data :

```
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] ([Actor_ID], [Actor_Name], [Movies_ID]) VALUES 
(1, N'A1', 2),
(2, N'A2', 1),
(3, N'A3', 3),
(3, N'A3', 4),
(2, N'A2', 6)

INSERT [dbo].[Table2] ([Movies_ID], [Movies_Name]) VALUES 
(1, N'M1'),
(2, N'M2'),
(3, N'M3')
(4, N'M4'),
(5, N'M5'),
(6, N'M6')

INSERT [dbo].[Table3] ([Movies_ID], [Revenue_generated]) VALUES
(1, 50),
(2, 100),
(3, 150),
(4, 75),
(5, 120),
(6, 115)
```

query :

```
Select
a.Actor_name,
b.Movies_name,
c.Revenue_generated
from
Table1 a
inner join Table2 b on a.Movies_ID = b.Movies_ID
inner join Table3 c on b.Movies_ID = c.Movies_ID
where c.Revenue_generated > 100 AND a.Actor_Name= 'A1'
```

replace 100 with desired value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prabhat. Can u explaim me how this qyery is workin step by step?

Comment: i got it. Thanks:)

Comment: @Mustang92 : you should read about `inner join` in sql from google. To help you get started, I joined the 3 tables based on common column(Movies_ID) as it is present in all 3 tables. Then a simple where condition filters out my desired result.

Comment: Can we write the above query using sub queries?

Comment: @ prabhat there is one problem with your answer. Your query will return all the movies that has generated revenue more than 100. But in my question i have asked list of all the movies by actor A1 which has earned more than 100 crores. i guess your query should be like this:

Select
a.Actor_name,
b.Movies_name,
c.Revenue_generated
from
Table1 a
inner join Table2 b on a.Movies_ID = b.Movies_ID
inner join Table3 c on b.Movies_ID = c.Movies_ID
where (c.Revenue_generated > 100 AND a.Actor-NAme= A1);

Please let me know if i am wrong?